# Electron: Size of contents in webview not rendered correctly

Tags: webview, electron

I have a problem with the webview of Electron. When the application opens and the contents of the webview are rendered, the width and height of the content is not sized correctly as you can see in the image below. The width and height of the webview itself is correct and does not need any change. If anyone knows how to fix this problem, let me know.

[image]